# Replace keys in Data.Map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, key

If I have two keys k0 and k1, which are in the Data.Map M, how can I remove k0 from the map and replace k1 with k0?

What would be the best approach to complete this task? I have tried to go through the documentation of Data.Map, but I have only been able to find functions which can change values.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I somewhat disagree with the downvote. The question could show some more effort, but the task at hand is small enough to be described precisely in one sentence, as done above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see,  there is no single library function which can perform this for you efficiently. However, you can roll your own doing something like this:

```
case M.lookup k0 myMap of
   Nothing -> myMap
   Just e  -> M.insert k1 e (M.delete k0 myMap)
```

This will require three map operations, costing O(log N) each.

We can do it in two operations as follows:

```
case updateLookupWithKey (\_ _ -> Nothing) k0 myMap of
   (Nothing, _    ) -> myMap
   (Just e, newMap) -> M.insert k1 e newMap
```

I don't think this can be further improved, since when dealing with two distinct keys we need to access twice the underlying balanced search tree anyway.